# Why December month only not loading when choosing option 12 in month drop down?

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I am working on full calendar.
I manually added month drop down ,after got reference from internet. 
So far it working properly. 
The problem is, Up to September, it works fine. 
But when I choose Oct, it shows Sep only, then for Nov- it shows Oct, and for Dec, it shows Nov only. December is not working in this drop down and calendar.

My code below:

```
$(".fc-right").append('<select class="select_month"><option value="">Select Month</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mrch</option><option value="4">Aprl</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">June</option><option value="7">July</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>');

$(".select_month").on("change", function (event) {
    $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month', this.value);
    $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('gotoDate', y + '-' + this.value + '-1');
}); // y assigned as selected year.
```

If I change option value for Oct to 11, Nov to 12 and Dec to 13, October and November back to normal, still December not working.

How to fix it. Kindly help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using your own dropdown to select the month, instead of using the controls that FullCalendar provides?

Comment: Without a working example, I'd assume you're probably not passing the plugin a proper/compatible date/value for the `changeView` or `gotoDate` methods.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [`changeView` takes the view as the first parameter (`'month'`), and a `Date` or equivalent string as the second](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView). You're passing a single number (as a string). Try passing in something like `'2019-' + ('00' + this.value).slice(-2) + '-01'` instead.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Doesn't `gotoDate` override that?

Comment: The second argument to `changeView` is optional, try leaving that out and just using `gotoDate`.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe? In which case the OP can try passing in that same value for the `gotoDate` call. I think the point is to use a properly formatted date.

Comment: There's probably no need for both `changeView` and `gotoDate`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for late reply, when I go through full calendar controls, I cant find proper one for my requirement, so I go with this one..

Comment: I use `gotoDate` mainly for change full calendar year, that I selected using another text box...and it works fine, only December month not showing.

Comment: It's suspicious that the problem happens for all months with 2 digits.

Comment: What happens if you change `-1` to `-2`.

Comment: @Barmar If you do that, the date format will still be invalid. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating valid date strings to pass to the fullCalendar functions.

1) `this.value` will be a single number. `changeView` expects you to provide a whole date (see [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/changeView)).

2) `y + '-' + this.value + '-1'` will produce dates like `2019-1-1` or `2019-10-1` which are not valid RFC2822 or ISO date formats, due to the single-digit values in the month and day sections.

You'll see a warning in the Console (generated by momentJS) when you try to use these values as dates because it cannot guarantee whether they will be interpreted correctly or not. Clearly in your case, there is some incorrect interpretation going on, leading to your issue. The [momentJS documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) gives you a clear list of supported date formats. See also the related [fullCalendar v3 dates documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/date-library).

Also, using both `changeView` **and** `goToDate` is redundant here. If you want to ensure that "month" view is chosen, then use `changeView`, and also pass a date. If you just want to change the date without caring about the view type, then use `goToDate`. For this example I'm going to assume you want `changeView`.

The fix is simple:

1) ensure all your dropdown options have a 2-digit value

2) set your hard-coded day string to a two-digit `01` as well

3) pass the full date string to the fullCalendar function.

```
$(".fc-right").append('<select class="select_month"><option value="">Select Month</option><option value="01">Jan</option><option value="02">Feb</option><option value="03">Mrch</option><option value="04">Aprl</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">June</option><option value="07">July</option><option value="08">Aug</option><option value="09">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>');

$(".select_month").on("change", function(event) {
  var dateStr = y + '-' + this.value + '-01';
  console.log(dateStr);
  $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month', dateStr);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f362m5du/2/

Comment: Why does it work with `2019-3-1` but it's off by 1 with `2019-10-1`? They both have a single-digit day part. Is it just an accident that it works for the first?

Comment: @Barmar I assume so. The JS Date constructor just does its best with whatever you give it, if it doesn't recognise the format. The results are not guaranteed. The behaviour may even vary between different browser engines. It does this instead of just throwing an error, which IMHO is a bit silly.

Comment: I thought it uses the moment.js parser, not the native JS parser.

Comment: fullCalendar does use momentJS, but the full warning you see in the browser from momentJS if you use a bad date string reads: _"Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info."_ So basically, momentJS can't read it and warns you. JS Date can't always read it either but doesn't warn you.

Comment: That makes sense. There are many other questions about strange results from the native Date parser.

Comment: @Barmar yep. It's a crock of s*** (IMHO), which is why libraries like momentJS are really helpful :-)

Comment: @ADyson Hi Ur one working for me in current year function perfectly, but in another function, I set `y` value as selected year, as per my code, `y` choose the year correctly, but when use this drop down, the year comes to current year. Lets say, I choose 2012,the calendar goes to Jan 2012, but, when I use drop down to chose April, it goes to April 2019. FYI,This functions worked fine on my old codes except that December problem.

Comment: @Riya well you didn't include the code for selecting the year in your question, so I can't be responsible for that specific part of the issue. For my demo I had to hard-code the year, because I had no way to know how you were creating that value. Did you accidentally copy my hard-coded `y = 2019` line into your own code?

Comment: `var year = $("#CalendarYear").val();  $(".select_month").on("change", function (event) {
                $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month', this.value);
                $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year + '-' + this.value + '-1');
            });`  This was the code, I used for this function. and for the Calendar year text box, I give choosing year only calendar link,so that four digit year only can load to text box like '2012','2015' etc..

Comment: @Riya I think you need to define `year` _inside_ the "change" function, so that you always select the latest value.

Comment: @Riya instead of creating your own custom controls for this, why not use something like a modified jQueryUI datepicker to select the month and year values? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7755/ . (You don't  have to attach it to a textbox, necessarily.)

Comment: actually, I use this same function in two different place, one is for current year, another one is for choosing past years. I gave codes for the current year in question, whereas, I forgot to mention assigning value for `y`. for my question funtion, `var y = new Date().getFullYear();` ,I assign value for y like dis

Comment: well that's why you always get the current year... try `y = $("#CalendarYear").val();` instead, to get the value chosen by the user

Comment: As, it is two different function, assign y or year is not an issue.Even though, I tried ur last answer `'y = $("#CalendarYear").val();` ,not working. FYI, If I assign `var year = $("#CalendarYear").val();` ,then I changed the code in change function as, `var dateStr = year + '-' + this.value + '-01';`.

Comment: without a full worked example it's going to be tricky to diagnose. As I said earlier, based on the little snippet you've shown I suspect the issue could be that you're setting a value for `year` at some other moment in the code, and if the user then changes the value in the textbox, and then selects the month, you aren't then reading the latest value. Try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zLh2swjb/

Comment: Thank You So much @ADyson. I found Out, Where I did a mistake, When I debug I found out, the code execute  another loop, so its not working, nothing problem with code. Thank you so much